# Married couples around a table

Tags: combinatorics

There are lot of similar questions available. After going through all, I am still confused with two different answers.

Question :  How many ways can three married couples sit around a round table if husband and wife must sit together?

Base on the explanation available in the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=gFo4LJmSe6gC&pg=PA17&lpg=PA17&dq=combinatorics%20problem%20about%20married%20couples%20around%20a%20table&source=bl&ots=38-CY7Xlqz&sig=NBE2euSLwuL4tjllyKgANqyIVrk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBmoVChMI3YqXhPKNxgIVkp28Ch1fWQCl#v=onepage&q=combinatorics%20problem%20about%20married%20couples%20around%20a%20table&f=false) , I get the answer as
$(3-1)! * 2^3  = 16$. This explanation is also clear to me.

However, after reading further [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=3-wi5WRMdd0C&pg=PA415&lpg=PA415&dq=In%20how%20many%20ways%20can%20married%20couples%20seat%20themselves%20around%20a%20circular&source=bl&ots=yfAtnR74yD&sig=lK6Z-oZoKt05NyA9F71Z6zA0eFA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEoQ6AEwB2oVChMIitXKo8ONxgIVynq8Ch0l3ACQ#v=onepage&q=In%20how%20many%20ways%20can%20married%20couples%20seat%20themselves%20around%20a%20circular&f=false), the number of ways in which three couples can be arranged around a circular table so that no wife sits next to her husband $= 120 -144 + 72 -16 = 32$ (based on inclusion and exclusion). If so, the number of ways where a wife sits next to her husband should be
$5! - 32 = 88$.

I know I am wrong. I am still trying hard to understand where I have gone wrong. Please help.

Comment: The $88$ (which I have not checked) is the number of ways  at least one pair of partners are next to each other. But not necessarily all.  So there are quite a few more than the $16$ where all pairs of partners are next to each other.

Comment: thanks  André Nicolas. that means 16 is the answer when every couples sits together , isn't it?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, $16$ is for all pairs together, $88$ is for at least one pair together.

Comment: thanks André Nicolas, I am clear now. how may I close this question now and select your answer?

Comment: To close things up, since the issue may come up for someone else, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We check your count of the number of ways *at least one couple* are in adjoining chairs. As you did, we use Inclusion/Exclusion. Call the couples A, B, and C.

The number of ways couple A are next to each other is $(2)(4!)$. For we may assume the fatter of the two members sits in a specific chair. Then the partner has $2$ choices, and for every such choice the rest can arrange themselves in $4!$ ways.

Add together the number of ways for couple A to be together, couple B to be together, couple C to be together. We get $144$.

But we have overcounted the ways in which for example couple A and B are both together. Again we can assume the fatter of the members of A sits in a specific chair. Then there are $2$ choices for where the other member sits, and then $(3)(2)$ ways for couple B to be together, leaving $2$ choices for the others, a total of $24$. Summing over all ways to choose $2$ couples, we get $72$.  So our corrected estimate is $144-72$.

But the $144$ counted  three times the arrangements in which all the couples are together, and so did the $72$, so we must add back the $16$ ways in which they are all together. The final count is $144-72+16$.

Note that this $88$ counts the number of ways *at least one couple* are together. It is naturally a much larger number than the $16$ ways in which *all couples* are together.