# Ways to seat $n$ couples around a circular table with restriction

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How many ways are there to seat $n$ couples around a circular table such that no couple sits next to each other?

I know that since there are $n$ couples, there are $2n$ people.

I need to use Inclusion-Exclusion. However I am unsure of how to go about this problem.

Comment: +1.For asking nice question. I am also expecting the answer for this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1324513/married-couples-around-a-table and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519406/couples-sitting-at-a-round-table and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744075/how-many-of-ways-arrange-people-seats-around-a-table and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765746/inclusion-exclusion-problem-sitting-arrangement and probably a dozen others.